# View source code for external library in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

External Library is usually used by including header files(*.h) and linking library files(*.dll). Other files(like *.cpp) are useful for reference. Visual Studio provides the "Go To Definition" menu to quickly jump to where the function defines, but only in the header files. So is there any way to quickly jump to the function implementation in the *.cpp files(source code are already provided)?

Comment: Do you have access to the .pdb files?  Can you rebuild them?  Is the C++ output files set to some generic filename like V90.pdb or something like $(TargetName).pdb.  If you manage to rebuild the .pdb files, put them in the same directory as the dll.  What you want might magically happen.

Comment: If the library isn't open source, then you will not be able to see the source code. If it is open source then you have to download the source code. You 've probably downloaded prebuilt libraries